# How to Implement a Mass Spring Damper Filter in Python

Tags: python, filtering, simulation

For context, I am working on a project that involves controlling a cursor with eye-tracking data. To achieve this, I am imitating the techniques described in the paper below:

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1741-2560/11/5/056026

So far I have successfully implemented the Kalman filter calibration process described in sections 2.2.1 and 2.2.2. The focus of my question is 2.2.3 which briefly describes an additional filter modeled after a mass spring damper system:

[image: mass-spring-damper-filter]

I would like to implement this filter for my project. However, the paper does not provide any additional details or references, and frankly I'm not sure where to start. I have found some resources for simulating mass spring damper systems in python, particularly the document below:

https://www.halvorsen.blog/documents/programming/python/resources/powerpoints/Mass-Spring-Damper%20System%20with%20Python.pdf

My problem with the examples in this document is that they each take a description of the system and an array of time steps as inputs and return the state of the system at those time steps as outputs. I need something that will behave like a filter that takes a single state as input and returns a filtered state as output. I'm not sure how to adapt the examples in this document to behave this way or if it even makes sense to try and do so.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Links to resources, useful python library recommendations, or example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the reference you cited, look at the section titled "Discretization."  It gives some formulas that allow you to calculate x(k+1) from x(k), and similarly for the first and second derivatives of x.  That allows you to advance the algorithm by one step in real time, and make feedback-based corrections before stepping again.  Perhaps you can try experimenting with the equations in the Discretization section without needing SciPy at all.

Comment: Thanks @PaulCornelius for pointing out that section. I had overlooked that section initially, but it turns out it was exactly what I was looking for.